# How can I find the general form equation of a line from two points?

Tags: geometry

Given the input:

```vb
double x1,y1,x2,y2;
```

How can I find the general form equation (double a,b,c where ax + by + c = 0) ?

Note: I want to be able to do this computationally. So the equivalent for slope-intercept form would be something like:

```vb
double dx, dy;
double m, b;

dx = x2 - x1;
dy = y2 - y1;
m = dy/dx;
b = y1;
```

Obviously, this is very simple, but I haven't been able to find the solution for the general equation form (which is more useful since it can do vertical lines). I already looked in my linear algebra book and two books on computational geometry (both too advanced to explain this).

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If you start from the equation `y-y1 = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1) * (x-x1)` (which is the equation of the line defined by two points), through some manipulation you can get `(y1-y2) * x + (x2-x1) * y + (x1-x2)*y1 + (y2-y1)*x1 = 0`, and you can recognize that:

- `a = y1-y2`,
- `b = x2-x1`,
- `c = (x1-x2)*y1 + (y2-y1)*x1`.

Comment: An additional benefit of this form is that the calculations won't bomb out even if the line is vertical, or if the two given points are the same. However, validation is still required *after* calculation, so that code that consumes the `a, b, c` parameters aren't caught in a surprise

Comment: Also, the values of `(a, b)` should be normalized to avoid numerical problems. Using the norm L2 is quite typical, so that `a^2 + b^2=1`

Comment: If you are using individual coefficients to make follow on calculations be aware that this might still give you issues when it is a vertical line since it does not produce a vertical in reduced form

Comment: You can simplify `c` to `x1 * y2 - x2 * y1` (distribute and collect).

Comment: You could also write `c` in terms of `a` and `b`.  as in `c= -(a*x1+b*y1)`

Comment: Just for future reference, This gives the coefficients in the form Ax + By = C instead of Ax + By + C = 0

Comment: @MojoJojo That's wrong, the coefficients are in form `a*x + b*y + c = 0`.

Comment: This seems to be wrong for me when I try it.. B has the wrong sign.. If I use b = x1 -X2 then its ok

Comment: I seem to be getting an error when I run this with (0,0) and (150,0) where I'm getting 150 for B instead of 1

Comment: @Paul - normal form is not unique. `0x + 150y + 0 = 0` describes the same line as `0x + 1y + 0 = 0`. In general, you can multiply `a` `b` and `c` by the same arbitrary (nonzero) constant and still get a description of the same line.

Answer (score 3):

Get the tangent by subtracting the two points `(x2-x1, y2-y1)`. Normalize it and rotate by 90 degrees to get the normal vector `(a,b)`. Take the dot product with one of the points to get the constant, `c`.

Answer (score 2):

If you start from the equation of defining line from 2 points

```
(x - x1)/(x2 - x1) = (y - y1)/(y2 - y1)
```

you can end up with the next equation

```
x(y2 - y1) - y(x2 - x1) - x1*y2 + y1*x2 = 0
```

so the coefficients will be:

- a = y2 - y1
- b = -(x2 - x1) = x1 - x2
- c = y1*x2 - x1*y2

My implementation of the algorithm in C

```
inline v3 LineEquationFrom2Points(v2 P1, v2 P2) {
    v3 Result;

    Result.A = P2.y - P1.y;
    Result.B = -(P2.x - P1.x);
    Result.C = P1.y * P2.x - P1.x * P2.y;

    return(Result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Shortcut steps:
"**Problem : (4,5) (3,-7)**"
**Solve:
m=-12/1** then
**12x-y= 48**
"**NOTE:m is a slope**"
**COPY THE NUMERATOR, AFFIX "X"
Positive fraction Negative sign on between.
(tip: simmilar sign = add + copy the sign)**
1.Change the second set into opposite signs,
2.ADD y1 to y2 (means add or subtract them depending of the sign),
3.ADD x1 to x2 (also means add or subtract them depending of the sign),
4.Then Multiply 12 and 1 to any of the problem set.
After that "**BOOM**" Tada!, you have your answer

Answer (score -6):

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    int a,b,c;
    char x,y;
    a=5;
    b=10;
    c=15;
    x=2;
    y=3;
    printf("the equation of line is %dx+%dy=%d" ,a,b,c);
}
```

Comment: This isn't AT ALL what the user was asking (and they asked it nearly 5 years ago). The code doesn't calculate anything; you've just worked it out manually, hardcoded it and printed it to the terminal. You've even restricted it to integers and chars(!?).

Comment: I've been an active member for more than 2 years and I haven't seen anything like this before :)