# How can i draw a line that starts from the bottom left corner of a window and ends at the upper right corner of a window using surface.set_at()?

Tags: python, pygame

Im trying to write a 2d renderer using pygame.
I decided to use the set_at() function to draw pixels to the screen, and it works just fine.
However, I want to draw a line with it and i cant figure out how.

I tried this:
running = True

```
running = True
while running:
    screen.fill(background_colour)
    for iex in range(screen.get_width()):
        for iey in range(screen.get_height()):
            draw_pixel(iex,iey, (255,0,0))
    pg.display.update()
```

I thought it would work, but turns out it just fills the entire screen.
Has someone had this issue before?If yes, please let me know.Thanks!

Comment: What is `draw_pixel()`? Do you mean `surface.set_at()` as mentioned in the title? If that is the case, your coordinates need to be a tuple, e.g. `surface.set_at((x, y), color)`.

Comment: yes, i made my own function for surface.set_at().How would i implement your solution in a for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using the [pygame draw line function](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.line) as suggested in the comments to the [above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75995476/2280890):

```
import pygame

WIDTH = 640
HEIGHT = 480
FPS = 30

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    # draw surface - fill background
    window.fill(pygame.Color("grey"))
    ## draw line
    # line(surface, color, start_pos, end_pos, width=1) -> Rect
    pygame.draw.line(window, "firebrick", (0, HEIGHT-1), (WIDTH-1, 0), width=1)
    # show surface
    pygame.display.update()
    # limit frames
    clock.tick(FPS)
pygame.quit()
```

This looks like the following:
[image: Diagonal Line]

If you would rather iteratively draw your line, then you'll need to work out the [equation for your line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13242831/2280890) (or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21565994/2280890)), iterate though the x-axis and call `draw_pixel()` with the corresponding y value.

I've extended the example to demonstrate the iterative approach:

```
import pygame

FPS = 30

p = (0, 0)
q = (300, 300)
# calculate line equation y = mx + b
# gradient y2 - y1 / x2 - x1
m = (q[1] - p[1]) / (q[0] - p[0])
# intercept b = mx - y
b = m*p[0] - p[1]


pygame.init()
# window = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0))  # fullscreen
window = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
# get the size of the window
width, height = window.get_size()
# set the titlebar
pygame.display.set_caption(f"Line Equation: y = {m}x + {b}")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    # draw surface - fill background
    window.fill(pygame.Color("grey"))
    # draw line from the bottom left to the top right
    # line(surface, color, start_pos, end_pos, width=1) -> Rect
    pygame.draw.line(window, "firebrick", (0, height-1), (width-1, 0), width=1)
    # iteratively draw line equation
    for x in range(width):
        y = round(m*x + b)  # set_at requires integers
        # set_at((x, y), Color) -> None
        window.set_at((x, y), "darkmagenta")

    # show surface
    pygame.display.update()
    # limit frames
    clock.tick(FPS)
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Ill try iteratively drawing it with your logic and ill mark it as the answer if it works, thank you!

Comment: This is my equation:
x = [0,0]
y = [300,300]
coefficients = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
polynomial = np.poly1d(coefficients)
x_axis = np.linspace(0,300,100)
y_axis = polynomial(x_axis)


When i run the program,i get this error:
numpy.linalg.LinAlgError: SVD did not converge in Linear Least Squares

Answer (score 0):

You are filling the entire screen with black pixels, if you consider the logic in your loops:

```
for iex in range(1920):
    for iey in range(1080):
        print(f"({iex}, {iey})")
```

You'll quickly notice that you'll get (0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), [...], (1, 0), (1, 1), etc.

What you want is more like this: (0, 1080), (1, 1079), (2, 1078), etc, but it gets a little more complicated than that since just adding one to x and y will only yield a diagonal on a square. Since most screens are in the aspect ratio 19:9 you'll need to calculate the y delta since the slope will vary based on your screen.

Comment: can you provide an example since im kinda dumb please?

Comment: I'm at work now and its not quite as trivial, but I strongly suggest you try to use a [line](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.line) function thats already implemented. You'll also need to learn how the coordinate system works, the zero point is in it the left upper corner, thats you (0, 0) point.